# Can't use certain Width - CSS menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I got this menu and I need all items to be the same width (155px).
But I don't seem to be doing it the right way, I would appreciate some tips and possible solutions.

```css
#menu {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 625px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#menu span {
  padding-left: 11px;
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
#menu li {
  background: url(../img/menu_dots.jpg) no-repeat;
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 614px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 155px;
}
#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D1D3D4;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#menu li .current {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current"><span>OCTO</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="equipa.html"><span>EQUIPA</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reconhecimento.html"><span>RECONHECIMENTO</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="parceiros.html"><span>PARCEIROS</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="porque_nao.html"><span>PORQUE NÃO?</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contactos.html"><span>CONTACTOS</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to change the display on the list items (`#menu li`) from `inline` to `inline-block`.

```css
#menu {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 625px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#menu span {
  padding-left: 11px;
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
#menu li {
  background: url(../img/menu_dots.jpg) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 614px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 155px;
}
#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D1D3D4;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#menu li .current {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current"><span>OCTO</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="equipa.html"><span>EQUIPA</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reconhecimento.html"><span>RECONHECIMENTO</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="parceiros.html"><span>PARCEIROS</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="porque_nao.html"><span>PORQUE NÃO?</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contactos.html"><span>CONTACTOS</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good solution but after adding `display:inline-block;` to `li` actual width wil be 166px, because of `padding-left:11px` also mind it;

Answer (score 0):

you need to add into the menu li the properties `overflow:hidden and max-width:155px and min-width:155px`